# Gradle build using Fabric plugin for Crashlytics with groovy plugins DSL

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

I had a perfectly good gradle build of an android app using Crashlytics and the standard Gradle setup as documented in the Crashlytics gradle doc.  I;m using Android Studio 3.2.1, Gradle 4.6 Android plugin version 3.2.1,

As part of prep to convert the build scripts to Kotlin later, I removed the buildscript and apply plugin clauses and replaced them with the plugins clause gradle supports and Kotlin requires. I have seen pure kotlin projects doing this successfully, but can't get this intermediate/prep step using Groovy to work.  The plugins clause is getting this error:

```
Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project.
```

Since the Fabric plugin does not exist in the gradle plugin portal (yet?), I'm using this settings.gradle and this part seems to work fine.  It finds the Fabric stuff no problem:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            switch (requested.id.id) {
                case "com.android.application":
                    useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
                    break
                case "io.fabric":
                    useModule("io.fabric.tools:gradle:${requested.version}")
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
include ':app'
```

It doesn't seem to matter if the com.android.application case in the switch is present or not, behavior is the same either way.

The corresponding plugins clause in the app's build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "signing"
    id "io.fabric" version "1.27.0"
}
```

In case it's useful the full exception stack from the sync attempt in the build looks like this:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'D:\Working\Monay\trunk\app\build.gradle' line: 5
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.fabric', version: '1.27.0', artifact: 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:232)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:184)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.fabric', version: '1.27.0', artifact: 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:247)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:229)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:125)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$3.run(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:151)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:225)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ExternalPluginsState.deriveFrom(ExternalPluginsState.groovy:23)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ExternalPluginsState$deriveFrom.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.apply(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:50)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.apply(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:164)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$200(DefaultPluginManager.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:252)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
    ... 99 more
```

For some reason Crashlytics plugin doesn't see the android app plugin this way.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or if this use of the plugins clause should work with the Fabric plugin? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

For others running into this, the simple fix is to skip applying the plugin in the `plugins{}` block, and instead apply it later in the build script (even immediately following the `plugins{}` block is fine):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("io.fabric") version("1.27.0") apply(false)
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```